# Python-like virtual environment for Mathematica?

Tags: packages, environment

Is there a way to control the versions of dependencies (packages) of Mathematica code, similar to virtual environments in Python (conda or venv), in the interests of reproducibility?

Comment: I don't think this exists yet, as package management isn't even standardized yet (it's getting there though). However, there are some ways to manage which version of a package gets loaded. With packages installed in the traditional way, I would adjust the `$Path` to control which version gets loaded. With installed paclets, I'm not sure what the best way is. There is `PacletEnable`/`PacletDisable` which can be used to effectively select a version, but they affect all sessions, not just the current session like `$Path` would. Hence no full answer from me.

Comment: If you deal with traditional packages and adjusting the `$Path`, perhaps you can use symlinking to add package to the "environment" that you are planning to include in the `$Path`. I assume that Mathematica can follow symlinks, but I have not tried it yet. Unfortunately, there are no symlinks on Windows.

Comment: @Szabolcs Symlinks do exist on Windows, and they should work fine for what you are suggesting. I have done very similar things in the past, and never ran into issues

Comment: @LukasLang Ah, it seems I'm way behind. The last Windows version I used daily was XP (my machine had the last generation of Intel integrated graphics that didn't support Vista/7) ... It appears that symlink support was added with Vista.

Comment: In principle, you can start Mathematica with the environment variable `MATHEMATICA_USERBASE` (see [`$UserBaseDirectory`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$UserBaseDirectory.html)) set to some other directory. This directory contains all settings, paclets & other customizations